# Am I able to fetch several strings from MySQL DB as a single 'glued' string?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table containing user names and cities:

- John | New York
- Aaron | New York
- George | Dallas
- Low | Dallas
- John | Dallas
- Young | Dallas

And I want to have a array as the following:

```
['New York'] => 'John, Aaron',
['Dallas'] => 'George, Low, John, Young'
```

So I think I need to concatenate strings within GROUP operator.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
select
city_name,
group_concat(user_names) as user_names
from table_name
group by city_name
```

Comment: This function uses `', '` as "glue", so if I need something else as  glue - I will bee in a deep sht. It would be better if there would be NO default glue at all, as I could use `group_concat(concat(user_name,' my glue '))`. Is there any thing I can do with a "glue"?

Comment: Read the manpage for the function. You can specify whatever glue char(s) you want.

Comment: Yes you can use as `group_concat(name SEPARATOR '||')` .. add whatever SEPARATOR you want.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b38d81/3)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`name` varchar(6), `city` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`name`, `city`)
VALUES
    ('John', 'New York'),
    ('Aaron', 'New York'),
    ('George', 'Dallas'),
    ('Low', 'Dallas'),
    ('John', 'Dallas'),
    ('Young', 'Dallas')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
concat('[''',city,'''] => ''',group_concat(name),'''') as array
from table1
group by city
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b38d81/3/0)**:

```
|                                 ARRAY |
|---------------------------------------|
| ['Dallas'] => 'George,Low,John,Young' |
|          ['New York'] => 'John,Aaron' |
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I was not as clear as was needed: I didn't mean that the result should be directly from MySQL.

Comment: However your effort to "simulate" PHP array look within MySQL syntax was impressive!